# WCF Service - catch global exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, logging

Im using enterprise library in order to handle exceptions, I need to know how can I catch everysingle exception without putting try/catch statements everywhere.

For example, im using caliburn micro on the client side which has the method : OnUnhandledException.

Comment: Are you asking for a WCF service or a WCF client?

Comment: WCF service, sorry forgot to mention that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a WCF Service you can create an [`IErrorHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation and register it. It will receive and be able to act on all exceptions created by the service implementation before returning to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to create custom class deriving *IOperationInvoker* and wrap method invocation in try/catch block.